# Laravel 5 Asyncronous AJAX requests cause session problems

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 ("laravel/framework" version is " v5.1.16", Homestead Ubuntu), with session driver = 'file'.

I noticed that if a number of async AJAX requests (jQuery) are fired eg. in autocomplete search form field then the session variables are gone.

This happens, only with async AJAX requests, when async option is set to false this problem no longer exists.

Also, when session driver is set to 'cookie' and async set to true there is a new cookie created on each AJAX request, so with 10 requests there will be 10 laravel cookies etc.

Any suggestions? I have failed to find any decent cause or solution to this, except not using async requests.

Related issues, which seems to be fixed.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7549

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5416

Comment: I'm having the exact same problems. I have script checking for new messages every few seconds. After a given number of requests que session id changes and all the session variables get lost. No idea why and I can't find any good answers. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I used cookies instead of session to hold some simple data.

Comment: This is a known issue - with no solution: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8172 - the problem is no one is able to provide a replicatable situation - it seems to be random, rare and no obvious cause.

Comment: They don't seem to be fixed actually, the first issue is closed as "known limitation", the second as "it's your app structure that's bad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of having an answer to this question and as "The Shift Exchange" already explained in his comment...

> This is a known issue - with no solution: [github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8172](http://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8172) - the problem is no one is able to provide a replicatable situation - it seems to be random, rare and no obvious cause.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue and the problem may have been a double-bind of the `web` middleware on a route. You should check that. I failed to notice that web was already applied in `RouteServiceProvider`. After removing `'middleware' => 'web'` on my problem routes, this issue went away completely.